# sharepoint rest lookup value

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

i'm having a minor issue. I'm using REST/JS to populate a dropdown box, which requires first getting the lookup of a column in a list.

```
//Product Model Cascade
document.getElementById("productDD").onchange = function() {
    var prod = this.options[document.getElementById("productDD").selectedIndex].text;
    var select = document.getElementById("productModelDD");
    $(select).empty();


    var call2 = $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists(guid'bb392616-24ee-47e2-9365-f17400348373')/Items", //the list
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }

    });
    call2.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var select = document.getElementById("productModellDD");
        for (index in data.d.results) {
            var parent = data.d.results[index].AT_ARMATECproducts; //Lookup column 
            console.log("parent var: " + parent);
            if (parent == prod) {
                var op = document.createElement("option");
                op.text = data.d.results[index].Title;
                op.value = data.d.results[index].Title;
                select.appendChild(op);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

but the parent value is coming back as "undefined" and i've triple checked that this is the correct list. I've also tried .get_LookupValue() but it comes back as can't get it from an undefined field.
So how do you get the value of a lookup field via rest?

EDIT:

I have done select/expand in the REST Query but have come up with a 400 bad request error:

```
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists(guid'bb392616-24ee-47e2-9365-f17400348373')/items?$select=Title,AT_ARMATECproducts/Title&$expand=AT_ARMATECproducts/Title",
```

Where AT_ARMATECproducts is the lookup field in the ARMATEC Product Models List. AT_ARMATECproducts is a lookup to the ARMATEC Products list which grabs the titles.

So, it turns out the lookup list was under a different name for some reason, it the list it shows up as AT_ARMATECproducts but seems to actually be AT_Products1.

```
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists(guid'bb392616-24ee-47e2-9365-f17400348373')/items?$select=Title,AT_Products1/Title&$expand=AT_Products1/Title",
var parent = data.d.results[index].AT_Products1;
```

now returns [object object], when I tried .Titles it returned with the Titles of the List not the lookup list. And when I tried .AT_Products1.Title it returned with undefined.

Answer (score 8):

When working with User/Lookup field values via SharePoint REST API it is important to differentiate between single-valued and multi-valued lookup fields.

### Single-valued lookup fields

Assume `Employee` list with a single-valued lookup field `Department`

Then the query: `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/items` returns lookup Id, for example:

```
getListItems(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'','Employees',
  function(items){
     if(items.length > 0)
        console.log(items[0].DepartmentId);   //returns LookupId
  },
  function(error){
     console.log(error.responseText);     
  });
```

The query:

```
 /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Employees')/items?$select=Department/Title,Department/Id&$expand=Department
```

returns projected Department object as shown below:

```
getListItems(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'?$select=Department/Title,Department/Id&$expand=Department','Employees',
  function(items){
     if(items.length > 0)
        console.log(items[0].Department.Title);   
        console.log(items[0].Department.Id);   
  },
  function(error){
     console.log(error.responseText);     
  });
```

### Multi-valued lookup fields

Assume `Employee` list with a multi-valued lookup field `Departments`

Then the query: `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/items` returns an array of lookup ids, for example:

```
getListItems(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'','Employees',
  function(items){
     if(items.length > 0)
        console.log(items[0].DepartmentsId);   //returns an array [LookupId1, LookupId1 .. LookupIdN]
  },
  function(error){
     console.log(error.responseText);     
  });
```

The query:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Employees')/items?$select=Departments/Title,Departments/Id&$expand=Departments
```

returns projected Departments array of objects as shown below:

```
getListItems(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'?$select=Departments/Title,Departments/Id&$expand=Departments','Employees',
  function(items){
     if(items.length > 0)
        if(items[0].Departments.results.length > 0) {
           console.log(items[0].Departments.results[0].Title);   
           console.log(items[0].Departments.results[0].Id);   
        }   
  },
  function(error){
     console.log(error.responseText);     
  });
```

---

SharePoint 2013 REST read operation function:

```
function getListItems(url, query, listName, success, failure) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items" + query,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data.d.results);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

`/_api/Web/Lists(guid'bb392616-24ee-47e2-9365-f17400348373')/items?$select=Title,AT_ARMATECproducts/Title&$expand=AT_ARMATECproducts"`

as you endpoint

The expand query should only contain the title of the lookup column, and should not include the lookup field. Your select is fine, but the expand isn't.

Answer (score 1):

below query finally worked for me

- **Merged** is a calculated field in **Cats** list
- **Cat** is a lookup field(which looks above Merged column) in the **MainFlat** list

  ```
          "?$select=Title,number,Cat/Merged&$expand=Cat" + 
          "&$filter=Cat/Merged eq '"+Merged+"'  "
  ```

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/152997/16880